# Исправлять ли ошибки интервьюируемого

Tags: пунктуация, орфография

Журналист взял интервью в письменном виде. Интервьюируемый не нарочно допускал ошибки, как орфографические, так и пунктуационные. Должен / вправе ли журналист их исправить перед публикацией?

Comment: Из справки о Сайте: Не задавайте вопросы.., не связанные напрямую с русским языком, предполагающие субъективные ответы со множеством возможных ответов или требующие одного, но очень длинного ответа.

Comment: Конечно должен, или он, или корректор. Газета должна быть грамотной. Если ж это выдержки из письменного текста и нужно показать его неграмотность, тогда пишут: орфография и пунктуация авторские.

Answer (score 3):

Журналист, вестимо, в своём праве, но его работа другая: отредактировать текст (редакторов в периодической печати не водится, только главный, он же политик, и дежурный - при выпуске номера в свет).

Если журналист ненавидит интервьюируемого, он запросто оставит в тексте всю гадость и укажет: орфография и пунктуация - авторские. Если такой цели - показать ослиные уши - у журналиста нет, то судьба текста решается в корректорской. Ошибок быть не должно.

(В газете "Правда" при СССР было двенадцать корректур!)